# How to debug this database connection string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=ACER-PC/SQLEXPRESS;Database=coupon;Integrated Security=true");
```

What's wrong in this?

Comment: what's the error you getting. mention the error then only we can able to help you.

Comment: network path not found this is the error i got

Comment: check the server name. You using  sql server or sql express and which version using.

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: could you checked the database is connecting through sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

A connection string for SQL Server should look more like:                             "Server= localhost; Database= employeedetails; Integrated Security=True;"

If you have a named instance of SQL Server, you'll need to add that as well, e.g., "Server=localhost\sqlexpress".

If it is not windows authentication then connection string will look like this,
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";

Comment: if i use '\' this symbol in "Server=localhost\sqlexpress". it shows an unrecognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

try this

add this code in web config file

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ProjectConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ACER-PC/SQLEXPRESS OR Your system ip address;Initial Catalog=coupon;Integrated Security=false;user=username;password=password"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

then initialize your connection string like

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
```